# Can't import local Python module in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, conda

I've created a Docker image containing a python project in a directory called `/service`. The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda:latest

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ADD . /service

WORKDIR /service

RUN conda env create -n my-env -f=environment.yml
RUN python setup.py develop

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Locally, to run the project from `/service` I do

```
source activate my-env
cd src
python app.py
```

And it runs correctly. When running the Docker image, if I do the same I'm given the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.core.metrics.metrics import ACTIVE
```

I have confirmed that `src/core/metrics/metrics.py` has indeed been included in the image, and that the file structure is the same as that of the local project.

I also added

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

to the beginning of `app.py` to see if there was an issue with the current working directory. Locally the printed result is `/full/path/to/project/service/src`. Within the Docker image, the printed result is `/service/src`, which seems to indicate the correct cwd.

Any ideas why `python app.py` doesn't work within the image?

Comment: What command are you using to run the docker image?

Comment: You need the PYTHONPATH varaible to point to the /service folder up to me. Add it to your Dockerfile...

Comment: Also, I dont know what `python setup.py develop` is doing but I would suppose that you need to activate your conda environment before running this command, don't you?